# How to turn a readonly property into readwrite property in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

What are the ways to turn a readonly property into readwrite property in Objective-C? Keep in mind I have no access to the source.

Reason for this: I need to do this in unit test for mock purposes.

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but why do you need to change the property?  Shouldn't other actions be driving the state of the property?

Comment: In my test, I want to overwrite the readonly property of a class I have no source code access to so I can test out different scenarios.

Comment: OK .. that almost sound like you are trying to mock the class you have no code to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the property's functionality like this without access to the main implementation block of the class, or at least the compilation unit that contains it, because you don't have any access to the *ivar* outside that unit. Even if you were to add a setter to the class in a category, you wouldn't be able to affect the class's storage any more than you can from entirely outside the class.

What you can do is use KVC, however. `setValue:forKey:` will bypass setters and go straight to the ivar *if it can find one*. You can use this to set any value you like even for a property that was declared `readonly`, provided there's backing storage whose name you know.

It goes like this:

```
//Passaquisset.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Passaquisset : NSObject

@property (copy, readonly, nonatomic) NSString * vanadium;

@end
```

---

```
//Passaquisset.m
#import "Passaquisset.h"

@implementation Passaquisset

@synthesize vanadium;

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    vanadium = @"Number 23";

    return self;
}

@end
```

---

```
//Elsewhere...
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Passaquisset.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Passaquisset * pq = [Passaquisset new];
        NSLog(@"%@", [pq vanadium]);

        [pq setValue:@"Number 24" forKey:@"vanadium"];

        NSLog(@"%@", [pq vanadium]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Like I said, this will fail -- actually raise an exception -- if there's neither a setter nor an ivar by the same name (or with an underscore appended `_vanadium` (KVC is pretty smart), such as if the property's value is entirely calculated:

```
//Passaquisset.m

#import "Passaquisset.h"

@implementation Passaquisset

/** KVC will fail with this version! **/

- (NSString *)vanadium
{
    return @"Number 23";
}

@end
```

For completeness, let me mention that if the property is backed by an ivar of an entirely different name (e.g., `@synthesize vanadium = erythronium;`), you'll need to know the *ivar's* name in order to use KVC.

Comment: Nice answer, KVC smartness in guessing is really useful!

Comment: Love the simplicity of the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply turn the property into `readwrite` and hope to access the setter, since the setter itself has not been synthesized, therefore it doesn't exist at all.

What you may think of doing is to guess the name of the ivar and add a setter at runtime.

Suppose your property is called `foo` and that is has the `copy` property.

1. Guess that the name of the ivar. Let's try with `_foo`.
2. Prepare a setter

   ```
   void fooSetter(id self, SEL _cmd, id newFoo) {
       Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(self, "_foo");
       id oldFoo = object_getIvar(self, ivar);
       if (oldFoo != newFoo)
            object_setIvar(self, ivar, [newFoo copy]);
   }
   ```
3. Add the setter to the class in the `resolveInstanceMethod:` class method

   ```
   + (BOOL) resolveInstanceMethod:(SEL)aSEL {
       if (aSEL == @selector(setFoo:)) {
         class_addMethod(self, @selector(setFoo:), (IMP)fooSetter, "v@:@");
         return YES;
       }
       return [super resolveInstanceMethod:aSel];
   }
   ```

At this point you have added the `setFoo:` method to your class at runtime, therefore you can access it by doing

```
YourClass yourObject = ...;
[yourObject setFoo:whatever];
```

Comment: Great idea and nicely done! KVC will do the ivar-name-guessing and all the rest of this for you, however. (See my answer ;).

Comment: I see, good idea as well. I didn't know about the "guessing capabilities" of KVC. I think the main difference between the two approaches is that adding a setter is sort of emulating a `readwrite` property, whereas KVC will just get the job done in a more straightforward way. At this point it really depends on the needs of the OP ;)

Comment: Great to know the method swizzling way apart from KVC. Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally -- I meant to say this earlier -- `resolveInstanceMethod:` might be a better choice of location for the `class_addMethod()` call. That's pretty much what its documented purpose is.

Comment: @Boon: This isn't truly swizzling. Swizzling means _clobbering_ an existing method (althogh you save the original version so you can call it).

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for pointing it out. It looks like the proper entry point indeed.

Comment: Right I was thinking about swizzling and subconsciously label this as that. :)

Comment: Although I guess clobbering also means that you don't have access to the original... @Boon

Answer (score 2):

I think overriding property that means redeclaring it again will work

In your .h file:

```
@property (readonly, copy) NSString *yourProperty;
In your .m file:

@interface MyClass ()

// Redeclare property as readwrite
@property (readwrite, copy) NSString *yourProperty;

@end


@implementation MyClass

@synthesize yourProperty;
@end
```

or

i am not tested but i think ,you have to try following

```
[youReadOnlyrProperty retain]
```

Comment: The property is from a class in Apple's framework. Will class extension work?

Comment: Tried, class extension won't work unless you have the source.

Comment: This is from NSView:"@property(readonly) NSInteger tag;"  And yet Apple claims that "Subclasses can override this property to provide individual tags for views, possibly redefining the property as readwrite so that you can modify it more easily."  I still don't see an easy way to do that.